# How can I set the test path in the config for blanket.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, blanket.js

I currently have all my tests in the root/test folder. Using blanket.js for code coverage works 100%. I want to move some of my tests into sub folders for example root/test/domainTests. However when doing this blanket.js does not find the test to run the coverage on. Is there an option i can set to point blanket.js to my tests? I have had a look around their site but cannot find anything useful.

current code in package.json - pattern points to my app files, not to the test files.

```
"config": {
  "blanket": {
    "pattern": "/domain/",
    "data-cover-never": "node_modules"
  }
```

I call it from the command line as follows

```
'mocha -r blanket -R html-cov > coverage.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the proper paths in in `package.json` file. In your example you are pointing to a folder, I think it needs to be a path that can locate the files.

```
"config": {
    "blanket": {
        "pattern": [
            "test/test1.js"
            "test/domain/test2.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

Also notice that you can use array for `pattern` property value if you need to specify more than one value (i.e. you moved only some of the tests, not all). Also wildcards (`*`) should also work for pattern values.

Comment: Pattern points to the files in my app not to the test files. I did try what you suggested however no luck. I was thinking maybe there is another option for setting the test file location?